# CMake and step-by-step debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, debugging, cmake

How can I debug step-by-step a project part of Visual Studio 2010 solution created by CMake?
The CMakeLists.txt has created the three projects ALL_BUILD, RUN_TEST and INSTALL, and other separate projects for each of the targets of the CMakeLists.txt
Tests are therefore created by CMake and so are listed in Visual Studio as separate projects to compile, in order to generate this way an executable for each test. I am not using the inner test framework offered by Visual Studio, because it seems that CMake are not taking it into consideration!!
Given that building RUN_TEST some tests fail, I would like to do a step-by-step debug of the tests, but it is not possible to do this by setting a test as start project. Moreover, the test has no command line arguments set if executed outside the RUN_TEST script.

Is there someone who knows CMake with Visual Studio 2010 ?

Does anyone know how I can debug my tests?

Tnx in advance

Comment: You use the CppUnitTestFramework from MS Visual Studio, right?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the framework you mentioned... Is it inside Visual Studio?

Comment: _but it is not possible to do this by setting a test as start project_ - Can you be more specific as to why this did not work out for you? Usually this is exactly what you need to do, set the failing test as starting project and run it with the debugger attached. The `RUN_TEST` project will just invoke a script that launches the different test executables in a row. You can still attach a debugger to those once they have started, but that is certainly not the most convenient way of debugging.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. Actually the single tests did not run because they were missing the .dll of the dependent submodules (other projects of the VS solution). By setting that all the generated .exe and .dll have to be put in the same output directory, the problem seems now to be solved, although the output dir is really a mess of files coming from all the projects' generation...

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the CppUnitTestFramework:

Open the Test View (Test / Windows / Test View). You should see a list of all tests there. Right click a test you want to debug and select "Debug Selection". That's it.

You may also select more than one test and debug them in this way.